# Add custom size fields to product in big cartel

Tags: html, angularjs, bigcartel

I have an online store on big cartel and some of the products may require an optional field where the user can type in his/her measures so that the product can be specifically designed for him/her. Although I am familiar on how to implement the front-end part of this, I am not quite sure how to make it comfortable for the vendor to have these extra info attached to each product so that when they visualize the order all these extra info are immediately attached to it.

My best case scenario is this:

The user picks a product and selects on the Size drop down choice the "Custom" option. At this point a little form will appear that they can fill with all the custom size they need. Now instead of attaching the string "Custom" to the product summary in the cart, I would like to have whatever they typed attached to it so that in the cart it will look something like:

[ PICTURE OF THE PRODUCT ] : product name - sizes typed by the user

This would make it easier for the vendor to understand what the user wants and will allow the user to purchase an item with custom size instead of the standard ones that might not be suitable for him/her (XS, S, M, L, XL).

Right now the code part that handles the size choice and submits to the cart looks like this:

```
<form id="product-form" method="post" action="/cart">

        {% if product.has_default_option %}

        {{ product.option | hidden_option_input }}

        {% else %}

        <div id="product-options" class="options">
                        <span>{{ Product_Options_Title }}</span>
                      {{ product.options_in_stock | options_select }}
        </div>

        {% endif %}

        <button id="product-addtocart" name="submit" type="submit"><span>{{ Add_to_Cart_Text }}</span></button>

    </form>
```

I thinks this is Angular which I am not very familiar with. But I think here is where I should make any change, I am also not very familiar with the big cartel framework, this is why I could use some pointers.

So my question would be, how do I edit the code so that the user can type in custom sizes and then attach what they typed to the product in the cart as the size they ordered ?

I understand my question might not be very clear so feel free to comment for clarifications. Keep also in mind that I would know how to implement the front-end part but I don't know how to interact with the back-end to make what I described happen. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but something like this isn't possible with Big Cartel - the platform doesn't support passing any additional information through the order process beyond what's already attached to the Product and the Product's Options.

Your best option is likely to instruct customers to add their custom information to the "Notes to seller" field at Checkout: https://blog.bigcartel.com/2014/04/22/introducing-notes-at-checkout/

You can find more information on editing Big Cartel themes here: https://help.bigcartel.com/developers/themes/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I guess I'll go with the notes =D

Answer (score 0):

Bigcartel now coming with grouped option. It's only active on paid plan. So you can add now size, color, design. Yes, you can add maximum three option variant.

Comment: Please refrain from adding advertisements for services to your Stack Overflow answers - it's not the purpose of the site. At a stretch you can add a comment under your answer, but it is at risk of being deleted in response to a "no longer needed" flag).